# What is the "-" (dash) command in zsh?

Tags: zsh

I accidentally/experimentally typed a `-` in my `zsh` session and hit return.  Nothing happened.

```
% -
% -
% echo $?
0
```

The usual methods don't tell me what it is:

```
% which -
% where -
%
```

What is this doing, and where is it defined?

In `bash`, I get the error I expected:

```
%# -
bash: -: command not found
```

It doesn't seem to be a tricksy executable like `[`:

```
% ls /bin                  
[*              dash*           expr*           ln*             pwd*            stty*           zsh*
bash*           date*           hostname*       ls*             realpath*       sync*
cat*            dd*             kill*           mkdir*          rm*             tcsh*
chmod*          df*             ksh*            mv*             rmdir*          test*
cp*             echo*           launchctl*      pax*            sh*             unlink*
csh*            ed*             link*           ps*             sleep*          wait4path*
```

Comment: As a sidenote, you need to use `which -- -` to get information about that command, `--` tells a lot of commands that no options will follow, but real arguments.

Answer (score 17):

That's a `zsh`-ism called a "Precommand Modifier". From the [docs](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Shell-Grammar.html#Precommand-Modifiers):

```shell
-    The command is executed with a ‘-’ prepended to its argv[0] string.
```

There are a few other precommand modifiers, such as `noglob` and `builtin`.  This one is for a very specific use case, where some shells will act as a login shell when invoked as `-bash` or `-ksh` or something similar:

```bash
bash -c 'echo $0'
# => bash
- bash -c 'echo $0'
# => -bash
```

With the dash, the shell usually loads some [different startup files](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/46856/432774). Outside of this usage, the `-` modifier doesn't really do much - in particular, `-` on a command line by itself will simply modify an empty command. That empty command in turn may trigger some hook functions, but won't do much else.

There's a bit more info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36388165) and [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/128983).

Comment: This seems like a good explanation, but it would be better if it also showed where it is documented that the docs' "preceded by a precommand modifier" implies that newlines between the modifier and the command name will not be treated as terminating the command.

Comment: @JohnBollinger - the precommand modifier needs to be part of the same command line; newlines are not allowed.  The newline was an artifact from copying the documentation - I removed it, and updated the answer with an example.

Comment: I'm looking at the newlines in the OP's example transcripts.  If newlines are not allowed between precommand modifiers and command names then the fact that `-` can serve as a precommand modifier does not (fully) explain the observed behavior.  That the OP (thinks they) executed `-` as a complete command seems to be the main point of the question.

Comment: The OP entered `-` as a standalone command line - it is a precommand modifier to an empty command.

Comment: Well that would be an important thing to add to this answer then.  Especially because the concept of an empty command is (I guess) another zsh-ism.

Comment: @JohnBollinger You can hit enter in `bash` or any other shell I've used and it does nothing...an empty command. I'd assume that's the same thing that's happening here; `zsh` eats the `-`, sets some sort of internal flag, then it's treated the same way hitting enter with nothing typed would be